# Changing one object property in an array changes all object properties

Tags: angular, ionic2

I have an Addon-model that has two properties - name:string and selected:bool. I store those in an array called addons. I have this as a property for another object (CartItem). When I change the selected property one of the addons, it is changed in all of the addons in that array. I want every array of addons in each CartItem to have its unique combination of Addons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bit difficult to understand what you mean, but I think you are putting the same object in your array many times, meaning that all the objects point to the same place in memory. Changing one of the objects changes all of them. Try creating unique objects instead of addind the same one in the array. `myArray.push(New AddonObject("testName", false));`